# What is row reduced echelon form? How to row reduce this matrix?

Tags: matrices

I'm not being able to grasp the concept of row reduced echelon form. Please, explain how to row reduce one of the the following matrices.

$A =
\begin{bmatrix}
    1&3&4&5\\3&9&12&9\\1&3&4&1
\end{bmatrix}$

$B=
\begin{bmatrix}
    1&2&1&2\\0&1&0&1\\-1&2&0&3
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Did you check [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form)?

Comment: A good example may be found here Definition 10.1:https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=1nahrqDT56QC&pg=PA363&dq=row+reduced+echelon&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEkQ6AEwCWoVChMI_Or9zN34xwIVxtcUCh0RNA8G#v=onepage&q=row%20reduced%20echelon&f=false

Answer (score 2):

In order to obtain the reduced row echelon form (rref) of a matrix, we apply some row operations. According to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form), for the first case we have:

$\begin{array}{l} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 3 &  9 & 12 & 9\\ 1 & 3 & 4 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\overset{R_2:=3R_1 - R_2}{\to}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & 4&5\\0&0&0&6 \\ 1&3&4&1 \end{bmatrix}\overset{R_3:=R_1 - R_3}{\to}\begin{bmatrix} 1&3&4&5\\0&0&0&6\\0&0&0&4 \end{bmatrix}\overset{R_2:=\frac 16R_2}{\to}\begin{bmatrix}1&3&4&5\\ 0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&4\\\end{bmatrix}\\\overset{R_3:=4R_2-R_3}{\to}
\begin{bmatrix}1&3&4&5\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\overset{R_1:=R_1 - 5R_2}{\to}\begin{bmatrix}1&3&4&0\\ 0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{array}$

The last matrix satisfies all the conditions of the reduced row echelon form of a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Reduced row echelon form is a specific echelon form of a matrix that can be obtained by modifying a matrix with basic row operations, such that every leading coefficient is 1 and is the only nonzero entry in its column.

Useful: http://www.math.odu.edu/~bogacki/cgi-bin/lat.cgi?c=rref

Answer (score 0):

You begin to put the matrix in echelon form, with the pivots equal to $1$, going downwards row after row. When that is done, all coefficients *under* a pivot (in the same column) are equal to $0$.Then you make the coefficients *above* the pivots equal to $0$, starting fom the last pivot and going *upwards*:
\begin{align*}
&\begin{bmatrix}
1&3&4&5\\3&9&12&9\\1&3&4&1
\end{bmatrix}
\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&3&4&5\\0&0&0&-6\\0&0&0&-4\\
\end{bmatrix}
\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&3&4&5\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}\\
\rightsquigarrow
&\begin{bmatrix}
1&3&4&5\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&3&4&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}